# How to get last modified date of the profile for microsoft graph api

Tags: php, api, microsoft-graph-api

Actually, We are trying to update images using CRON job

- 1) We have to fetch last updated date of the image if that is older
  then 1 day then we are updating on the local server
- 2) Currently we are updating all images, therefore, taking too much
  time to update also has a time limit of 1hr to Access token

  $response = $graph->createRequest('get', '/users/' . $employee_id . '/photos/64x64')
  ->setReturnType('GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream') 
  ->execute();

Comment: I'm doing a similar operation, and like the OP, I would like to get as last modified/updated value for the photo or, lacking that, the user record.

In the nearly 4-years since this thread started, has MS updated the Graph API to be able to get this information about a user profile pic or the user records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) We have to fetch last updated date of the image if that is older then 1 day then we are updating on the local server.

Based on my test, We couldn't get the last modified date of the user's profile. According to [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity), there is not a property about the user's modified date.

> 2) Currently we are updating all images, therefore, taking too much time to update also has a time limit of 1hr to Access token

If your request will take more time to complete, we can refresh the accesstoken before the accesstoken expired. For more information, we can refer to [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user#5-use-the-refresh-token-to-get-a-new-access-token).